# Tensorflow error with dataset iterator initialization in monitoredtrainingsession

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator

Hi everyone i need somehelp.
I try to code resnet-101 imagenet classification using tensorflow without using estimator. I try it to study deep learning and understand how to use tensorflow. 
My problem is monitoredtrainingSession does not initilize my iterator.

I have read some article about the problems and try to use hook to handle it but it fails and i have no idea why it fails.

after i create monitoredtrainingsession it first initialize train_iterator
and got outOfRange exception
then validation step are performed.

It seems fine for now but after finish runing validation and try to run training step again. I got Error related with iterator.get_next().
It saids I did not initialize iterator but my hook function clearly call

```py
 session.run(self._initializer, feed_dict={filenames: self._filenames})
```

i'm sure because i can see the below message that i print to check if it is initialized or not.

```py
iter_val.initializer after_create_session is called 0 times
```

what am i wrong with it?

running flow are like below

1. run train step fine (epoch =0)
2. run validation step fine (epoch =0)
3. run train step Error(epoch =1)

Please ignore horovod(hvd()) in the code cause I am not using it right now.

Here is my code so please help me to fix it and let me know what's wrong with my code.

```py
class _DatasetInitializerHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    def __init__(self, initializer, filenames=[], name=""):
        self._initializer = initializer
        self._filenames = filenames
        self._name = name
        self._cnt = 0
        self._before_runCnt = 0

    def begin(self):
        pass

    def after_create_session(self, session, coord):
        del coord

        if len(self._filenames) == 0:
            session.run(self._initializer)
        else:
            session.run(self._initializer, feed_dict={filenames: self._filenames})
        print(self._name, "after_create_session is called {} times".format(self._cnt))
        self._cnt += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        nlogs = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        nlogs = 0

    hvd.init()
    b_imagenet=False
    if b_imagenet:
        training_filenames = ['/data/tfrecords/imagenet2012_train_shard{}.tfrecord'.format(i) for i in range(129)]
    else:
        training_filenames = ['/data/cifar-10-tfrecords/train_shard{}.tfrecord'.format(i) for i in range(1, 2, 1)]

    filenames = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None])

    trainData = dataset_input_fn(is_training=True, filename=filenames, nworkers=hvd.size(), workeridx=hvd.rank(),
                                 batch_size=FLAGS.batchSize, prefetch_size=FLAGS.prefetch_buffer_size, repeat=1,
                                 shuffle_buffer_size=FLAGS.shuffle_buffer_size)

    valData = dataset_input_fn(is_training=False, filename=FLAGS.validationfile, nworkers=hvd.size(), workeridx=hvd.rank(),
                               batch_size=1,prefetch_size=FLAGS.prefetch_buffer_size, repeat=1, shuffle_buffer_size=1)
    # Pin GPU to be used to process local rank (one GPU per process)
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = str(hvd.local_rank())

    for i in tqdm(range(FLAGS.nepoch)):
        shuffle(training_filenames)
        model = model_class(nCls=FLAGS.nClasses, img_width=FLAGS.width, img_height=FLAGS.height,
                        learning_rate=FLAGS.learning_rate, weight_decay=FLAGS.weight_decay)

        iter_train = trainData.make_initializable_iterator()
        train_op = model.build_model(iter_train.get_next(), is_trainig=True, hvd=None)

        train_hooks = [hvd.BroadcastGlobalVariablesHook(0),
                       _DatasetInitializerHook(iter_train.initializer, training_filenames, "iter_train.initializer")]


        with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(checkpoint_dir="./tmp/train_logs", config=config, hooks=train_hooks,
            save_checkpoint_secs=30) as sess:

            try:
                while True:
                    opt = sess.run([train_op])
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
              pass

        iter_val = valData.make_initializable_iterator()
        prediction_result = model.build_model(iter_val.get_next(),is_trainig=False, hvd=None)

        validation_hooks = [hvd.BroadcastGlobalVariablesHook(0),
                            _DatasetInitializerHook(iter_val.initializer, [], "iter_val.initializer")]


        with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession( checkpoint_dir="./tmp/train_logs",config=config, hooks=validation_hooks) as sess:
                try:
                    while True:
                       result = sess.run([prediction_result])
                except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                   pass
```

This is the error message I got.

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: GetNext() failed because the iterator has not been initialized. Ensure that you have run the initializer operation for this iterator before getting the next element.
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at workspace/multi_gpu/main.py:128) ]]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node IteratorGetNext:
 IteratorV2_2 (defined at workspace/multi_gpu/main.py:126)

Comment: I'm facing similar problem. Did you figure out any solution for this?

Comment: sorry for late comment. but i could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your initializer into a scaffold:

```
scaffold = tf.train.Scaffold(local_init_op=train_init_operator)
```

and give it to the `monitoredTrainingSession` with:

```
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(scaffold=scaffold, ...
```